# Dbms_Stats.Gather_Table_Stats after partition exchange in Oracle procedure?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have an oracle procedure that inserts all the rows from "table1 Partition (P1)" into table2.  I update a field in table2 and then swap the partition back to table1:

```
Alter Table table1 Exchange Partition P1 WITH TABLE table2 Including Indexes Without Validation;
```

This works.

Question: Do I need to gather table stats after? Code:

```
EXECUTE  Dbms_Stats.Gather_Table_Stats (Ownname => 'MySchema', Tabname => 'Table1', Partname 
=> 'P1, Granularity =>  'ALL', Degree => 32);
```

Takes a long time to run and there are some other issues involved.

thanks a lot, I've googled and can't find a definitive answer

- Steve

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `exchange partition` the statistics of the table will become the statistics of the partition and the statistics of the partition will become the statistics of the table, i.e. the statistics are exchanged too.

Here I have a table with three partitions and originally all statistics are there:

```
0:admspm@spmdtz> printStats -p location -- (*)

Table_Name|object_Type   |subobject  |last_Analyzed|num_Rows|sample_Size|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCATION  |Table         |           |06.04. 15:23 |     817|        817|
LOCATION  |TablePartition|PARTITION_1|06.04. 15:23 |     272|        272|
LOCATION  |TablePartition|PARTITION_2|06.04. 15:23 |     272|        272|
LOCATION  |TablePartition|PARTITION_3|06.04. 15:23 |     273|        273|
```

Now a swap out a partition and swap it back in:

```
0:admspm@spmdtz> create table xxx as select * from location where par_id=3;
Table Xxx created.
0:admspm@spmdtz> alter table location exchange partition partition_3 
                 with table xxx;
Table Location altered.
```

and the statistics are gone:

```
0:admspm@spmdtz> printStats -p location

Table_Name|object_Type   |subobject  |last_Analyzed|num_Rows|sample_Size|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCATION  |Table         |           |06.04. 15:23 |     817|        817|
LOCATION  |TablePartition|PARTITION_1|06.04. 15:23 |     272|        272|
LOCATION  |TablePartition|PARTITION_2|06.04. 15:23 |     272|        272|
LOCATION  |TablePartition|PARTITION_3|             |        |           |
```

However when I analyze the swap table 'XXX'

```
0:admspm@spmdtz> stats -gT xxx -- (*)
```

And swap back in, I get correct statistics again

```
0:admspm@spmdtz> alter table location exchange partition partition_3 
                 with table xxx;
Table Location altered.
0:admspm@spmdtz> printStats -p location

Table_Name|object_Type   |subobject  |last_Analyzed|num_Rows|sample_Size|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCATION  |Table         |           |06.04. 15:23 |     817|        817|
LOCATION  |TablePartition|PARTITION_1|06.04. 15:23 |     272|        272|
LOCATION  |TablePartition|PARTITION_2|06.04. 15:23 |     272|        272|
LOCATION  |TablePartition|PARTITION_3|02.10. 18:24 |     273|        273|
```

---

(*) these commands are made available by the [senora](http://senora.sourceforge.net/) tool

Comment: Hello Martin, thanks for the guidance.  Each partition has hundreds of millions of rows, and the logic to update the specific fields is rather complex.  It takes about 10 minutes to process a partition, and the end users of the data are concerned about its availability.  So... 1) Insert records into Swap table using "Insert into... Select..." (joins to other tables...) 2) Exchange partition back into source.  The only reason I'd consider gathering statistics is if it's needed to "commit" the changed data in some way.  That's what I couldn't find out with research...

Comment: Also, the Oracle Schema / User under which the process runs doesn't have permissions to gather statistics on the Source table, which resides in a different schema.  I can create a Procedure in the Source table's schema and grant execute to PROCESS_USER schema but I need to ask the DBAs for permission to that.  Thanks again - Steve

Comment: I just ran a short test and found my answer to be incorrect. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Martin, that's great thank you.  during the process, I gather statistics on table2.  so when i exchange the partition back to table1, it takes care of it automatically.  Very helpful!  thanks